# Reading request param from httpservlet request

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I have using rest service. I have following request.
http://127.0.0.1:29070/webbrokerproxy/wbservice/secure/basket/wbrokere
In this i am using wbrokere as request param.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/basket/{brokerid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getAllBasket(@PathVariable("brokerid") String brokerid,HttpServletRequest request) throws PTWebException {
    Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();
    while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();
        String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
        for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
            String paramValue = paramValues[i];
            log.info("paramname : " + paramName + "param value : " + paramValue);
        }
    }

    Map<String, Object> baskets = basketService.getBrokerBaskets(brokerid);
    if (baskets != null)
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(baskets, HttpStatus.OK);
    else
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(baskets, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

Now if suppose from httpservelt request i need to log all request parameter names and value how i can log this?

Comment: You're already doing it. What you're missing is that `wbrokere` is not a request parameter. It's a path variable. That's why it's annotated with `@PathVariable` and not with `@RequestParam`. A request param is what you find after the `?`in a URL: `/search?query=foo&lang=fr`. query and lang would be two request parameters.

Comment: But from request do we have anyway to read its value and name.

Comment: Its value is "wbrokere". It's stored in the variable `brokerid`. So you can read its value by using the variable `brokerid`. It doesn't have any name: the url is `/basket/wbrokere`, not something like `/basket/somename=wbrokere` (which wouldn't be a valid URL)

Comment: Inmy project further I am forwarding this request there i need to log information ofr paramter names and value.There i do not have rest controller so how i should log it

Comment: It's just some part of the URL, that you consider being a path variable. You can ur getRequestURI(), and split by `/`, and get all the parts if you want.

Comment: Yes thats one way which I have thought but problem is that i will only get wbrokee I will not get (brokerid)

Comment: brokerid is just the name of a Java variable. It doesn't appear anywhere in the URL. Your requirement doesn't make much sense.

Comment: my requirement is in case of any exception we are sending one mail with stacktrace  which has all request parameter name and values so developer comes to know what details client have sent.So for this purpose i needed both brokerid and wbrokere

Comment: No. You just name the complete URL. The developer will then see what this URL maps to, and deduce tha the Java variable that you chose to name brokerid had the value wbrokere.

Comment: Right.This will be better to send complete url.Thanks